# HOC is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I am trying to implement a simple HOC in REACT but for some reason, this error keeps popping up.

> (0, _hocFunctionName.hocFunctionName) is not a function

here is a link to the sandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-voice-le93k?file=/src/App.js)

I am not sure what is the problem and I searched for what might be wrong but haven't found a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting using a default export, but then trying to import using a named import. They'll need to either both be default, or both be named.

So either change the import to:

```
import withFallOut from "./withFallout";
```

Or change the export to:

```
export function withFallOut(WrappedComponenet) {
```

Comment: >Super expression must either be null or a function ////

I did that but this happend

Comment: Check your spelling of `React.Component`